# What is the meaning of "deep route misery"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

It's a song (Chemical - CRASHDÏET) about drugs(in my opinion), but I can't understand the 
"deep route misery" in the lyric. I know "deep misery", but the "route" here is really confused. So could any one explain that for me? Thanks.

lyric:

```
Don't you know
it runs deep down in my bones
And I want it now
I need it now
Can't you see
this deep route misery 
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      
that you inflict
It makes me sick
Feel good chemical
Feel good chemical
I gotta get this off my chest
how could you say I was obsessed
cause I can't conceal
a love thats real?
so I broke your golden rules
your regulations too
But I can't rewind
time is so unkind.
Feel good chemical
Feel good chemical
All I need is another hit
yeah one last fix to keep the blues at bay
All I need is another kick
just one last kiss of death then I'll be on my way
All I need is another hit
yeah one last fix to keep the blues at bay
All I need is another kick
just one last fix of that I feel good chemical
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what was meant is [deep-rooted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deep-rooted) . It may be a transcription error, a spelling mistake or a genuine misunderstanding or confusion on the part of the text writer.

Comment: @oerkelens I search it again and I find some lyrics is "deep root" (not deep rooted). So, is "deep root" make sense?

Comment: @oerkelens Could also be deliberate "poetic license" to drop a syllable and therefore fit the tune.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's "Deep-Rooted" misery (which sounds the same - so probably an error by whoever wrote it)

Deep-Rooted means "Having a persistent influence" or "Firmly Embedded"

So Deep-Rooted Misery means "Really persistent misery"

Comment: I search it again and I find some lyrics is "deep root" (not deep rooted). So, is "deep root" make sense?